# Как добавить в БД MySQL дату последнего визита пользователя?

Tags: php, mysql, html5, phpmyadmin

Всем привет. Есть БД в phpMyAdmin registrartion и таблица users, где хранятся id, username, email и password зарегистрировавшегося пользователя. PHP:

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>email</th>
    <th>last login</th>
</tr>

  <?php 
  $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');

  $query="SELECT*FROM users WHERE id>0";

  mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

  $result=mysqli_query($db,$query) or die(mysqli_error($db));

  for($data=[];$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);$data[]=$row) ;
  $result='';
  foreach($data as $elem) {
    $result.='<tr>';
    $result.='<td>'.$elem['id'].'</td>';
    $result.='<td>'.$elem['username'].'</td>';
    $result.='<td>'.$elem['email'].'</td>';
    $result.='</tr>';
  }
  echo $result;


 ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Этот код выводит значения в виде таблицы из базы данных на страницу. Но как можно занести дату последнего логина пользователя в БД и , следственно, вывести на страницу?

Зараннее огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, где-то есть процедура логина пользователя. Туда необходимо добавить выполнение запроса:

```
"UPDATE users SET last_login = NOW() WHERE username='$username'"
```

где $username - отфильтрованное от ненужных символов имя пользователя. Разумеется, в таблице должен существовать сам столбец `last_login` (или как он у вас в таблице называется).

Comment: Ответ не раскрывает всех необходимых действий ибо   
 `таблица users, где хранятся id, username, email и password` и в вашем ответе нет ни слова о том что необходимо завести отдельное поле для хранения, так же стоило бы уточнить человеку нужен последний "логин" или всё-же "время последнего посещения"

Comment: Владимир Клыков, я написал "Разумеется, в таблице должен существовать сам столбец last_login (или как он у вас в таблице называется)".
Если автор запроса предоставит более подробную информацию о самой таблице и процедуре логина, можно будет помочь ему с более конкретным примером.

Comment: приношу извинения если это действительно было в тексте, видимо под вечер прочел по диагонали ваш ответ =)

Comment: Извините за копипаст, постараюсь быть точнее: https://pastebin.com/NgDXMnhg. Это процесс логина, т.е. если в массиве errors() ошибок нет, перенапрвить на домашнюю страницу(index.php). В базе данных есть ячейка lastlogin, куда должна заноситься дата. Я пытался сделать так: https://pastebin.com/nQC2aksa, но безуспешно. Еще пытался эти три строки с датой вставить в начало гостевой страницы, но тоже не удалось.    В самом вопросе представлена сама гостевая страница, а в ссылках строки из файла server.php

Comment: Давайте по порядку. Строчка `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');` не нужна: у вас осталось соединение по которому вы проверяли логин/пароль. Время тоже не имеет смысла готовить на php: попробуйте функцию MySQL NOW(), как я показывал в примере. В общем, попробуйте поставить предложенный выше вариант запроса с измененными названиями полей: `"UPDATE users SET lastlogin = NOW() WHERE username='$username'"` т.к. у вас ошибка как минимум в этом запросе. Проверьте, что в итоге окажется в базе.